# ng-change event not firing for text input in bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I am kind of stuck here. I have an application which uses bootstrap modal with couple of text boxes which has values from server. When i open the modal for the first time and remove the items from textbox ng-change event fires. Once all the fields are cleared, i closed the modal. When i opened the modal again it is populated with new values but when i remove the item from the textbox ng-change event is not triggered.

But here i found one more strange thing, the above mentioned problem occurs only if we have one item in textbox.

Here is my html code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input only-numeric class="floatLeft" name="scoreSample" type="text" ng-model="scoreSample" id="scoreSample" ng-change="sampleMethod()" ng-model-onblur>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input only-numeric class=" floatLeft" name="errorSample" type="text" ng-model="errorSample" id="errorSample" ng-change="sampleMethod()" ng-model-onblur>
  </td>
</tr>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.sampleMethod = function () {
  alert("Coming here");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have posted the code.

Comment: Where did you define the `sampleMethod` function? Btw, the [input](http://devdocs.io/html/input) must not have an end tag ;)

Comment: thanks glepretre.. :) sampleMethod function is in my controller(myctrl.js).

Comment: Could you try without your ng-model-onblur directive please?

Comment: i tried after removing that as well, but no luck :(

Comment: @tanuj make sure that you've got a dot in your ng-model expression (!)

Comment: @ pkozlowski.opensource i didn't get you. In which expression there should be dot?

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: i think u have to post the entire view and controller, so that we know whats going on.

Comment: You have to post more code so that we can see what's going on. You should also try debugging with console.log statements to find out when things are being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for this happening are listed in the documentation:

---

The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will not be evaluated:

if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed

if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null

if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value
Note, this directive requires ngModel to be present.

---

Have you checked these things? Other than that I also think you should post the entire view and controller as it is very difficult to find an error in the snippet you posted already.